# Amplify AWS Graphql filter is not working with limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, graphql, limit, aws-amplify

For example, if there are ten students in the class and you want to find three who scored 80, as of now, it works as follows: they retrieve the first three students and filter the scores as 80, then it does not check from the fourth to the tenth student. It should eventually filter out students who have a score of 80, and then it should select three.

Here is the code what I'm trying to do: I want to filter out those that contain "featured" in "tags" and I want 3 results. tags is a string array.

```
const filter = {
      tags: { contains: 'FEATURED' },
    };

await API.graphql({
        query: listTestsByStatus,
        variables: { status: 'APPROVED', filter: filter, limit: 3 },
      });
```